# In microservice architecture, what is the difference between proxy pattern and aggregator composition pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, microservices, backend, proxy-pattern

In its simplest form, **Aggregator** invokes multiple services to achieve the functionality required by the application.

**Proxy** is a variation of Aggregator. In this case, no aggregation needs to happen on the client but a different microservice may be invoked based upon the business need

but Proxy can be of two kinds
*smart* and *dumb*

and if the Proxy is smart, what's the difference from an Aggregator pattern?

Comment: An aggregator may be fetching the resources up front, having already aggregated some, or all, of the resources before becoming requested. A proxy should never aggregate data in my opinion. In that case you should call it something else. Proxy is more of a middleware kind of service, looking at it from an infrastructure perspective.

Comment: I think the main confusing part here is that the Proxy can call multiple services if needed. That does not mean within the one transaction. Only one service can be used as a proxy for the number of services.  Proxy is just hidden from the actual service. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

in Aggregator Pattern we have Combined request ,then aggregator Break The Reaquest to Send to Provider services and Get Response for Deliver To Consumer

But In Proxy Pattern Consumer Dont Know The EndpointAdress and Send Request To ProxyService

**notice**:Request In  Aggregator Pattern are Composit But In Proxy Pattern  Request Are Composite or Simple